# How to show and hide a div section based on the boolean value returned from my api response

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

I want to load a div section based on the status of the response from an api call,

- I have a search box, on entering the value and click, if true is
  returned then the div section is open
- If false then the section remains close or should close.

  APPROACH TRIED - defined a variable and using it as a condition at the div
  section,

ISSUE - Works fine on the second click, but on the first click of the search never loads the section even if the value returned is true, instead on the second click works.

The below is the component code

```
export class EndorsementComponent  implements OnInit{
  fetch_endorse: any;

    onSubmitPolNo() {
          let formValueE: any = {
            request_param : this.endorsSearchForm.value.searchViaPFEG,
          }  
          this.endorsService.getEndorsePolicy(formValueE)
            .pipe()
            .subscribe(endorsearchdata => {
              this.displayEndorseSearch(endorsearchdata),
                console.log('endorsearchdata: ', endorsearchdata); //
              (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            }
            )
        }
        displayEndorseSearch(endorsearchdata): void {
          this.endorsearchdata = endorsearchdata;
          console.log('endorsearchdata: ', endorsearchdata); //
          if (this.endorsearchdata.status == false) {
            this.fetch_endorse = false;
            const message = this.endorsSearchForm.value.searchViaPFEG + `  Does not exist.`;
            this.layoutUtilsService.showActionNotification(message, MessageType.Update, 10000, true, false);
      
          }
          else {
            this.fetch_endorse = true;
            console.log(this.endorsearchdata.status)
          }
```

And the below is the html

```
    <div *ngIf ="fetch_endorse" class="m-portlet">
  <form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--group-seperator" novalidate [formGroup]="endorsForm" >
    <div class="m-portlet__head">
      <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
          <span class="m-portlet__head-icon m--hide">
            <i class="la la-gear"></i>
          </span>
          <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text">
            Policy Detail
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
          <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text w-100">
            Endorsement Status:
          </h3>
          <mat-form-field class="no-line in-line example-full-width flex:1">
            <h3>
            <input matInput formControlName ="endr_status">
          </h3>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="m-portlet__body">
        <div class="m-form__section m-form__section--first">
            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
        <label class="col-lg-1.5 col-form-label">Policy Number:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput formControlName ="policy_number">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <label class="col-lg-1.5 col-form-label">Insured Name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input matInput formControlName ="insured_name">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Via using the css to hide and show 
added the following style to the css

```
  ::ng-deep .show {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 1s;
}

::ng-deep .hide {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

HTML - Gave an ID to my Div to refer it at the component

```
    <div #myDiv  class="m-portlet">
  <form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--group-seperator" novalidate [formGroup]="endorsForm" >
    <div class="m-portlet__head">
      <div class="m-portlet__head-caption">
        <div class="m-portlet__head-title">
          <span class="m-portlet__head-icon m--hide">
            <i class="la la-gear"></i>
          </span>
          <h3 class="m-portlet__head-text">
            Calculate Detail
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
```

At the component added this condition

```
export class EndComponent implements OnInit {
  public fetch_endorse: boolean = false;
  @ViewChild("myDiv") myDiv;

  ngOnInit() {
 this.fetch_endorse = false;
    this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.add("hide");
    this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.remove("show");
}

functionTest(){
    this.fetch_endorse = this.endorsearchdata.status;

    if (!this.fetch_endorse) {
      this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.add("hide");
      this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.remove("show");
}
  else {
      //this.fetch_endorse = true;
      this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.add("show");
      this.myDiv.nativeElement.classList.remove("hide");
}

}
}
```